# Toolbar (v7) showing as a white space, however buttons work

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, android-toolbar

So yeah, i'm looking for a solution online to this issue since 3 days ago but i couldn't find anyone having this same problem.

This only happens in my Galaxy Note 2 Android version 4.4.2.

What happens is that the toolbar works when i'm using an virtual machine with android 5.0, but unfortunately if i install it in my cellphone it renders as a white space. The funny part is that its buttons work (up button to open my drawer layout). Any clue on this?

Method where i startup my Toolbar:

[image]

My main Activity Layout:

[image: Activity Layout]

My toolbar XML:

[image: Toolbar XML]

The problem itself:

[image]

Comment: Try removing the theme attribute, see what you get.

Comment: Hello. Removed the theme but the problem still occurs

Comment: Are you extending AppCompatActivity? ActionBarActivity has been replaced recently.

Comment: Yes, i'm already using it. It didn't work even before the last support library update.

Comment: I've tried your code. It works, so there might be some important part of your code that isn't here. Are you calling getSupportActionBar().hide(), maybe you shouldn't.

Comment: You've tried it on android 4.4.2? Unfortunately there's nothing more in my code related to the toolbar apart from what i've posted above. :/

Comment: I only have 4.4.4 on Genymotion.

Comment: Use ?attr/actionBarSize for minHeight attibute

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti nothing happened..

Comment: post your ToolbarCustomTheme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to fix this problem until google released the new `AppCompatActivity` within the appcompat library. Basically it is a substitute to the `ActionBarActivity` which eases the implementation of the new `Toolbar` on pre-lollipop devices.

To anyone interested: [Example usage of AppCompatActivity in Android](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2015/04/24/example-usage-of-appcompatactivity-in-android/.)

Comment: Thanks and sorry 'bout that :)